# Error with SonarQube sacanner and jacoco.exec file

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

i've got an error when i performan analyse on my project (java 1.8) with jenkins with SonarQube scanner.
When it try to read the jacoco.exec report, the job fail and the following error is set :

> ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Metric 'overall_lines_to_cover' should not be computed by a Sensor
>     at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.DefaultSensorStorage.saveMeasure(DefaultSensorStorage.java:240)
>     at org.sonar.scanner.index.DefaultIndex.addMeasure(DefaultIndex.java:231)
>     at org.sonar.scanner.deprecated.DeprecatedSensorContext.saveMeasure(DeprecatedSensorContext.java:131)
>     at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.JaCoCoOverallSensor$OverallAnalyzer.saveMeasures(JaCoCoOverallSensor.java:101)
>     at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.AbstractAnalyzer.readExecutionData(AbstractAnalyzer.java:150)
>     at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.AbstractAnalyzer.analyse(AbstractAnalyzer.java:114)
>     at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.JaCoCoOverallSensor.analyse(JaCoCoOverallSensor.java:80)
>     at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:57)
>     at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:49)
>     at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:78)
>     at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:182)
>     at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
>     at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
>     at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:247)
>     at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:242)
>     at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:240)
>     at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:232)
>     at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
>     at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
>     at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
>     at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
>     at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
>     at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
>     at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:115)
>     at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:116)
>     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
>     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
>     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
>     at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:110)
>     at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:74)
>     at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)

I use SonarQube scanner 2.8 with the Sonar 6.2 release and the 3.10 java plugin.

The problem seems to have appeared since i upgraded the Sonar server from 5.3 to 6.2...

Can anyone help me with this issue ?

My apologies for my approximate English.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the version of your Java plugin

Comment: yes, done : it's 3.10 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've seen the same problem "Metric 'overall_lines_to_cover' should not be computed by a Sensor" here.

Version of the Java plugin was 3.14.

After update to 4.4.0.8066 the issue disappeared.

Thanks for pointing out @G.Ann.

Comment: I will upgrade the java plugin. I did not think about it

Comment: Ok it's working !! i also had to upgrade my findbugs plugin. thank's a lot !

Comment: @Matthias  "by updating the java plugin" what do you want to say? Is it any plugin configured in Jenkins? Sorry I am new to these devops tools and facing the same issue